# Apresentar Relatório ITEXTSHARP em um Formulario

Tags: c#, itextsharp

Como apresentar o relatorio itextsharp em um formulário? Sem precisar salvá-lo em PDF.  Apenas exibí-lo em um formulário.  Da mesmá forma que podemos fazer no reportviewer.

Comment: Não entendi, se você não quer gerar um pdf, por que precisaria do `iTextSharp` para gerar esse formulário?

Comment: Sim eu quero gerar o PDF.  Mas gostaria de saber como exibir o relatorio gerado em um form. E não em um leito PDF convencional.

Answer (score 0):

Penso que a única forma seria utilizar o componente `COM` do **Acrobat Reader** (como é óbvio, obriga a ter a aplicação instalada):

1. Botão direito na sua `ToolBox` e selecionar "Escolher items" (*Select Items*)
2. Aceder ao separador "Componentes COM"
3. Procurar e selecionar "Adobe PDF Reader" e clicar OK

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

4. Fazer o *drag & drop* do controlo para o seu `Form`
5. Para abrir o PDF basta alterar a propriedade `src` para o caminho do seu PDF

Resposta dada no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504442/viewing-pdf-in-windows-forms-using-c-sharp).